# Hadoop output values can't access from web service

Tags: servlets, hadoop, mapreduce

I develop a program with Hadoop and Web service. I make three hadoop classes , Driver, Mapper and Reducer. And the other class is servlet. I invoke the hadoop driver class from servlet and hadoop is work properly. But I want to read the text from hadoop's output folder and how can I do for that? Because, the hadoop's output folder is not appear when run the servlet and it appears when the program is finished. So, I can't access the text in part-r-00000 file within output folder. 
I put these four class together in same package. Myproject>src>sourcecode>Driver,Mapper,Reducer,Servlet

Input text file is in WEB_INF.

This is my driver class.

```
package sourcecode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class ALDriver {

    public ALDriver() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException,
            InterruptedException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Job job = new Job();
        String input = "/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/WebContent/WEB-INF/al001012010.txt";
        //String output = "/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/WebContent/WEB-INF/output";
        String output = "/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/WebContent/WEB-INF/output";

        System.out.println("Here ****************************************");
        // Create a new job

        // Set job name to locate it in the distributed environment
        job.setJarByClass(ALDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("ALABAMA");

        // Set input and output Path, note that we use the default input format
        // which is TextInputFormat (each record is a line of input)
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(input));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));

        // Set Mapper and Reducer class
        job.setMapperClass(ALMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ALReducer.class);

        // Set Output key and value
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Total time : " + elapsedTime);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);


         //DeleteFolder.deleteDirectory(new File("/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/output"));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ALDriver AL = new ALDriver();

    }

}
```

This is mapper class.

```
package sourcecode;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;



public class ALMapper extends 
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private static final int MISSING = 9999;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String recordnumber = line.substring(16, 23);
        int population = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(24));      
            context.write(new Text(recordnumber), new IntWritable(population));

    }
}
```

This is reducer class.

```
package sourcecode;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;



public class ALReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int maxValue = 150000;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {  
            if(value.get() > maxValue){
                //maxValue = value.get();
                context.write(key, new IntWritable(value.get()));
            //System.out.println("The Output: " + key + " and " + value.get());
            try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/WebContent/WEB-INF/outputtxtfile.txt", true)))) {
                out.println( key + " = " + value.get() );
            }catch (IOException e) {
                //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
            }
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("The Output: " + key + " and " + maxValue);
    }
}
```

This is the servlet and where I invoke the Hadoop Driver class.

```
package sourcecode;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Readtxtfile
 */
@WebServlet("/Readtxtfile")
public class Readtxtfile extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean receive = false;
    /**
     * @throws IOException 
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Readtxtfile()  {
        super();


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");       
        try {

              File file = new File("/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/WebContent/WEB-INF/outputtxtfile.txt");

              if (file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("File is created!");
              }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
              }

            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //CallingHadoop c = new CallingHadoop();
        String release = "/WEB-INF/output";
        Path path = Paths.get(release);
        //receive = c.callHadoop();
        try {
            ALDriver a = new ALDriver();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //
        // We are going to read a file called configuration.properties. This
        // file is placed under the WEB-INF directory.
        //

        //ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
        //ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin().getPluginPreferences().setValue(ResourcesPlugin.PREF_AUTO_REFRESH, true); 
        //if (Files.exists(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)){



        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title> Census Data Test </title></head>");
        out.println("<body bgColor=\"Green\" >");
        out.println("<h1>Census Data Analytics with MapReduce </h1>");  

        //String filename = "/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/output/part-r-00000";

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        //
        // First get the file InputStream using ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()
        // method.
        //
        String filename = "/WEB-INF/outputtxtfile.txt";
        InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);

        if (is != null) {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            //PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            String text = "";

            //
            // We read the file line by line and later will be displayed on the 
            // browser page.
            //
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(text);
                //
                out.println("<p>"+text);
                //text.replaceAll(text, "");
                }                   
        }
         //File oldFile = new File("/WEB-INF/outputtxtfile.txt");

         //oldFile.deleteOnExit();
         //DeleteFolder.deleteDirectory(new File("/home/hadoop/HadoopEclipseWorkspace/WebTest2/WebContent/WEB-INF/outputtxtfile.txt"));

         System.out.println("Done!");
    }




    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }


}
```

How can I get the output of the hadoop in runtime?

Comment: Is it at all working? What I understand is you have used apis of hadoop. I have few queries : Are you referring to local file system? BTW how are you submitting job to hadoop cluster?

Comment: Yes, I refer to local file system.This program is not work with hadoop HDFS cluster. If I want to connect with HDFS cluster, I change the input and output path in Driver class (eg. hdfs://localhost:8081/user/root/). If I don't want to connect with cluster but I want to work with mapreduce. So, I import the external hadoop libraries to my project. But now I faced in not synchronized with hadoop mapreduce output.